# how to add account on dapp

Tags: dapps, myetherwallet, metamask, ens

I tried to bid a name on ENS but it says

> "no accounts added to dapp"

I have metamask google extension linked to myetherwallet.

Please let me know how to add an account on dapp.

Thank you!!!

Hiro

Answer (score 1):

So in the Chrome bar at the top right, click the hamburger menu
[image: click the hamburger menu]

---

then click import account

---

[image: click import account]

Now you have 2 choices via the dropdown either

---

A input your private key

---

B add the json file (you may wish to have a relatively small amount of ETH in this account from a security perspective)

---

[image: paste in your private key]

---

or..

---

[image: import the Json from your backup Keystore]

Alternatively you could generate an address from within Metamask and send a few ETH to it but that may be O/T I suppose...